# Unable to set slider input to maximum

Tags: html, input, range

We are not able to set slider to max value for this perticular input. Is there any way that we can handle that issue with javascript?

```
<input type="range" min="2" max="10" step="3" />
```

Comment: Why do you have to start at `2`, go up in `3` and have no more than `10`?

Comment: Let’s assume that I can also set slider value from outside e.g. with number input.

Comment: Do you want the slider to abide by the attributes if the user tries to change the slider after it has been changed to `10`?

Comment: I would like to be able to set slider value to 10.

Comment: So you want it to be able to be set to 2, 5, 8 and 10?

Comment: That’s right and handle should go to the most right.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the slider so that snaps in place at either `2`, `5`, `8` or `10` and I have set the default value of the slider to `2`. There are also markings next to the slider, so that the user can see which values are valid.

The JavaScript works by rounding the value of the slider to the closest number in the sequence `2`, `5`, `8` and `11`. Because the slider only goes up to `10`, when it attempts to round it to `11`, it automatically caps it at `10`.

**I have provided a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/nstmh0ax/).**

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");

slider.addEventListener("change", function() {
  let rounded = (Math.round((this.value - 2) / 3) * 3) + 2;
  slider.value = rounded;
});
```

```html
<input type="range" min="2" max="10" step="any" value="2" list="slider-marks" id="slider">

<datalist id="slider-marks">
  <option value="2"></option>
  <option value="5"></option>
  <option value="8"></option>
  <option value="10"></option>
</datalist>
```

---

## Modified Version

I have modified the code to snap the slider into place as the user changes the value. However, markings cannot be used as they do not display properly and the slider flickers a little bit between `5` and `8`.

**I have provided a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/nstmh0ax/63/).**

```js
const slider = document.getElementById("slider");

setInterval(function() {
  if (slider.value >= 8) {
    slider.step = 2;
  } else {
    slider.step = 3;
  }
  let rounded = (Math.round((slider.value - 2) / 3) * 3) + 2;
  slider.value = rounded;
}, 0);
```

```html
<input type="range" min="2" max="10" step="3" value="2" id="slider">
```